(Paradoxical?) Dynamic Bidding Brainteaser
I've been thinking about this scenario: Player I and Player II each sample a number randomly (uniformly) from $[0,1]$. They put their numbers in a box and start bidding sequentially with player I making the first bid. The game continues until a player passes (i.e. refuses to bid in their turn), in that case the other player wins the sum of the numbers put in the box. I'll assume that you can bid any positive real number strictly greater than the last announced bid, otherwise you lose. What is the optimal bidding strategy here?
My   thought process: Let $s$ and $r$ be the sampled numbers of players I and II respectively. From player I's perspective the box is valued at $s+1/2$. If I opens with a bid of $\beta$ then player II knows that $\beta<s+1/2$ since it's irrational for player I to ever bid higher than what his expectation of the value of the box. This means $s>\beta-1/2$. So if $\beta<1/2$, player II has no additional information about $s$ other than what she already knows that $s>0$. so the game continues until one of the players bids something greater than $1/2$. Things get interesting here: Say player I bids $\beta_1>1/2$. Now player II knows $s>\beta_1-1/2$, so she updates her belief about the value of the box from $r+1/2$ to a greater value: $r+ (\beta_1-1/2+1)/2=r+(\beta_1+1/2)/2$. Now it's her turn, let's say she bids $\gamma_1>\beta_1$. Now player I knows that $\gamma_1<r+(\beta_1+1/2)/2$ or equivalently $r>\gamma_1-(\beta_1+1/2)/2 ~~(>0)$. So he updates his valuation of the box from $s+1/2$ to $s+ (\gamma_1-(\beta_1+1/2)/2+1)/2 = s+(\gamma_1-\beta_1/2+3/4)/2$. To continue this process, assume that after $2n$ bids where it's now player I's turn, his current valuation is $s+u_n$ and player II's valuation is $r+v_n$. player I will bid some $\beta_{n+1}$, so II knows that $\beta_{n+1}<s+u_n$ or $s>\beta_{n+1}-u_n$, so player II updates her valuation to $r+(1 +\beta_{n+1}-u_n)/2$. Now comes her turn so she bids $\gamma_{n+1}<r+(1 +\beta_{n+1}-u_n)/2$ (remember that $\beta_1<\gamma_1<\dots<\beta_n<\gamma_n$). Thus player I updates his valuation to $s+(1+\gamma_{n+1}-(1 +\beta_{n+1}-u_n)/2)/2$. So we have the following recursion:
$$v_{n+1}=(1 +\beta_{n+1}-u_n)/2$$
$$u_{n+1}=(1+\gamma_{n+1}-(1 +\beta_{n+1}-u_n)/2)/2$$
Intuitively, it appears that both players have no incentive to stop increasing their bids, so they will have a negative profit at the end (after an infinite number of bids). Please either correct my intuition or explain how one could proceed to tackle this problem.
